# Checkpointing the IndexedDB file on IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, indexeddb, localforage

I have a hybrid app that runs on IOS and Android. It uses IndexedDB to store persistent data, via the localForage package (see GitHub).

My problem is that over time the sqlite3-wal file gets massive (2+GB) when the actual data is only 30MB or so.

Can anybody let me know how I could go about checkpointing the database to constrain the size of the WAL file. Or any other options to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Any update on this Steve? We're experiencing the same symptoms.

Comment: In short no and I still regard it as my biggest issue to resolve. I contacted tofumatt (localForage) who was surprised that the WAL file was not cleaned somehow and passed the buck saying that it was an IOS issue.

Comment: I noticed this problem happens when overwriting an existing key within the storage. If you first remove the key before replacing it we a new value the the size off the app doesn't seem to grow. It's kind of a hack but it will have to do for us until a fix comes along. Another solution would be to use another driver (e.g. websql)

Comment: Thanks for this. I will certainly put this approach in as a temporary solution.